# Chances of random number belong to a given set

Tags: probability

I have 23 elements and 7 of them belong to a given set.

5 of these 23 elements will be picked randomly, I want to know the chances of at least one of those selected 5 elements belong to the aforementioned set of 7.

The possible combinations of picked elements do not contain repeated elements.

I coded [this PHP script](https://gist.github.com/LucasZeta/01f512c74a8fd95bfad2) to calculate the chances but I believe there is a formula to solve this kind of problem and you'd be kind enough to show me.

Thank you!

PS.: This is not some homework I'm lazily asking you to do for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability is given by:
$$ 1-\frac{\binom{23-7}{5}}{\binom{23}{5}} = 1-\frac{\binom{16}{5}}{\binom{23}{5}}=1-\frac{16\cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot 12}{23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20\cdot 19}\approx\color{red}{87\%}.$$
Can you guess why?

Comment: Because 16/23 are the chances of picking a number that does not belong to the set of 7 out of the 23 elements.


The numbers are decreasing because as you pick a number it is not available anymore.


It's necessary to multiplicate the results because you are adding one probability to the other (you're picking 16/23 *and* 15/22 and so forth).


I failed to translate my problem to math terms, once you guys showed the answer it is clear that it was not that hard.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that **none** of those elements belongs in the set is:

$$\frac{\binom{23-7}{5}}{\binom{23}{5}}=\frac{624}{4807}$$

So the probability that at least one of those elements belongs in the set is:

$$1-\frac{624}{4807}=\frac{4183}{4807}$$

Answer (score 0):

Call "good" elements each of 7 belonging in the group, other 16 are "bad" ones.
So:
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{picking at least 1 "good" element}) = 1- \mathbb{P}(\text{picking always "bad" elements}) = \\
1- \frac{16}{23} \cdot \frac{15}{22} \cdot \frac{14}{21} \cdot \frac{13}{20} \cdot \frac{12}{19}$$